# $where in mongodb web shell not working

Tags: mongodb, find, where-clause, mongodb-query

i have the below set of test documents which i inserted in to the mongodb and when i use to query the db using the $where get the below exception

Error: database error: $where query, but no script engine

Any idea why the $where clause not working

test data :

```js
db.things.save({ "_id" : 1, "domainName" : "test11.com", "hosting" : "hostgator.com" })
db.things.save({ "_id" : 2, "domainName" : "test2.com", "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com"})
db.things.save({ "_id" : 3, "domainName" : "test3.com", "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com" })
db.things.save({ "_id" : 4, "domainName" : "test4.com", "hosting" : "hostgator.com" })
db.things.save({ "_id" : 5, "domainName" : "test5.com", "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com" })
db.things.save({ "_id" : 6, "domainName" : "test6.com", "hosting" : "cloud.google.com" })
db.things.save({ "_id" : 7, "domainName" : "test7.com", "hosting" : "aws.amazon.com" })
db.things.save({ "_id" : 8, "domainName" : "test8.com", "hosting" : "hostgator.com" })
db.things.save({ "_id" : 9, "domainName" : "test9.com", "hosting" : "cloud.google.com" })
db.things.save({ "_id" : 10, "domainName" : "test10.com", "hosting" : "godaddy.com" })
```

query used :

db.things.find( { $where: "this.domainName == 'test11.com'" } );

Answer (score 0):

Please don not use the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator unless you absolutely need to. And then please do not use the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator.

There is a better way:

```js
db.things.find({ "domainName": "test11.com" })
```

That is the standard query form. You should almost never use [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), and if you think you do, then please post your question here so we can set you straight.

Namely:

- [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) makes a JavaScript comparison, which means an interpreter instance is spawned to evaluate the condition. This is undoubtedly **slower** than the native code evaluation that would happen otherwise.
- [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) As documented, throws away the ability to test the evaluation of the condition against an index due to the casting and transference to the Interpreter instance. So again this is **very** bad for performance.
- There is almost **always** a native implementation that will be backed by the native code interface that will do this both **better** and **faster** than is possible by invoking a JavaScript interpreter. If it does not exist now, then it will work in the future.

The overall point here is that your form of query is not required as it is something that MongoDB does in a native way already.

Additionally, since you seem to be referring to the "online test shell", with any common sense the option to disable JavaScript execution which is available to `mongod` processes has been invoked if not otherwise implemented in the API that is handling the client transfer.

That last makes sense to avoid possible hacker exploitation attacks, but MongoDB is generally ( in latest versions ) very secure from such script injection as "could" otherwise be possible by allowing JavaScript to be specified in the arguments available to an open environment.

Comment: May i know why we need to avoid $where , it is the thing provided by mongodb standard only correct ?


and , when i used this form of $where it is not working 

db.things.find( { $where: function() { return (this.domainName == "test11.com") } } );

with this query we expect a single document only (all test document posted in the question) , but this query is giving all the documents , may i know why this $where clause is behaving like this ?


if their is issue with $where , why mongo is not fixing this issue .

Comment: @Bravo There is nothing for MongoDB to fix. It is your usage that is incorrect. See the edits where I explain this and otherwise the rationale why this functionality would not be exposed.

Answer (score 0):

The error might be coming because on mongodb server, server-side execution of JavaScript might have been disabled, to check this use sh.status().

"$where" queries should not be used unless strictly necessary: they are much slower
than regular queries.

Also check these links how "where" clause can be used for NoSQL injection.

https://support.mongolab.com/entries/23442437-25-March-2013-Disabling-server-side-JavaScript-injection

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_NoSQL_injection